# MCU ADC and signal conditioning circuit layout

Tags: adc, layout

What are the rules of thumb for physical spacing of signal conditioning circuitry (say - some sort of high-speed sensor followed by a voltage follower opamp followed by a RC anti-aliasing filter)?

Should the RC filter be close the ADC pin?

I did see some noise injected the ADC pin, which results in various ADC sampling artifacts.

Note that this question focused on the physical layout.  Adequate precautions have been taken in the schematic design.  The firmware has been fully debugged.

Answer (score 1):

In general the RC filter should be as close as possible to the ADC pin.  Much of the layout issues relate to the other traces in the neighborhood.  Most of the noise (other than shot noise/etc) is coupled from somewhere.  Running traces at right angle to other traces with fast edges, using a 4 layer board and putting a solid ground under your ADC signal trace, and putting a resistor between the ADC input and ground (to lower the input impedance of the ADC and reduce noise sensitivity) will all help reduce the noise.